# How to open an XPage document data source in notes client using the selected Notes document

Tags: xpages, composite, frameset, domino-designer-eclipse

I need to open an xpage in notes client and send a unid to the xpage from a document or view (which is not in xpages)

The xpage is embedded in a composite application and added to a frame. 
Not sure propertybroker is the right thing to use as the notes client document is not part of the composite app.

I am now opening the xpage from an action in the notesdocument using @Command([OpenFrameset];"myxpage") but need to send in the unid to the selected document to the xpage so I can show the document data in the xpage.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an XPage not set to run on server, environment variables may be a way. Because it's running locally, it should point to the Notes Client's notes.ini, not a server one. Admittedly I haven't tried.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use an action that open the xpage directly using the notes: protocol and send in the unid as a url parameter

n:= @If(@DbName="";"";@URLEncode("Domino"; @Name([CN]; @ServerName)));
@URLOpen("notes://" + n + "/" + @WebDbName + "/someXpage.xsp?OpenXPage&action=openDocument&documentId=" + @Text(@DocumentUniqueID))

Thanks to Jesse Gallagher
http://www.notessidan.se/blogg.nsf/xstart.xsp?post=4C2357FE3B08F322C1257D9A00501BA9